# Changing “Willing to Move/Relocate” setting in a LinkedIn profile

Tags: linkedin, profile

I remember setting the *willing-to-relocate/move* field when I first created my LinkedIn profile. I need to change it now, but I cannot find the setting anywhere. I have tried searching for `will`, `move`, `relo` in the profile editor, the public profile, but there’s *nothing*; [even Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=change%20linkedin%20willing%20to%20move) [isn’t helpful](http://www.google.com/search?q=modify%20linkedin%20willing%20to%20relocate).

How do I change it?

Comment: are you sure you are not confused with the "Careers" site of stackoverflow ? Check here : http://careers.stackoverflow.com This is the only place I remember seeing "willing to relocate".

Comment: It’s a pretty standard job-profile field and I’m pretty sure I had seen it on LinkedIn. I certainly get a lot of jobs for other cities which are useless right now, so I need to filter those out in some/any way.

Comment: Oddly that field still exists on Stackoverflow, but no longer seems editable: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354047/where-is-the-willing-to-relocate-option-in-my-job-match-preferences